# Pytorch class torch._C.TensorBase information?

Tags: pytorch

I am wondering from where the tensor._c.TensorBase comes from?Can Someone please tell me the c source code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Quite hidden, currently under [torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable.cpp](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/csrc/autograd/python_variable.cpp).

More general information is available in [this discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/where-does-torch-c-come-from/2015).